# Parallel and Sequential Processing in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 3 processors running parallel I want to wait untill all have finished their jobs. All 3 processors will put the message in kafka topic once they finish their job. And once all have finished I want to trigger the next job. For this I explored the possible options like below.

1. Use wait-notify. wait after all 3 processors and then notify for the next job
2. Put each processors status in DistributedMapCache then on every put message in kafka topic check this cache and all 3 processors status is done then trigger next job
3. write some poller who will keep on polling these 3 processors and trigger next jobs

What is the best way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [**`Wait-Notify`**](http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/) will be the **`bestway/cleaner`** to achieve this case.

- We can also acheive the same case using Merge Content processor for waiting 3 flowfiles and then trigger the next job (there are some cases where [this](http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/#why-mergecontent-dont-suffice) solution won't work).

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/139521/how-to-know-when-a-job-finish-to-start-next-job-on.html) link for more details.

Comment: Can you check this I have used wait & notify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55629056/wait-notify-for-parallel-sequential-processing-in-nifi