# Wait-Notify for parallel & sequential processing in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I have a requirement where I need to execute 4 jobs parallel and when same items job is done in all 4 processors parallely then trigger the next processor for this I have used wait-notify

Flow is like
4 parallel jobs -> notify (release signal identifier = ${itemid}, signal counter name = ${processorname}) -> wait (release signal identifier = ${itemid}, target signal count = 4) and wait relationship is connected to the same wait processor-> next processor

This works for first time but I have noticed that wait queue is not cleared even after the target signal count condition is met and i guess that is the problem it is not working for subsequent flows.

It should clear the waiting queue once the criteria is met right?

Comment: This is tagged minifi, did you see the same behavior in regular NiFi?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Yes